# Reflect point inside Poincarè Disk Model

Tags: circles, hyperbolic-geometry

I have a question: is there a formula which map points onto the Poincarè Disk Model starting from points which are outside the unit Disk?

For example, I have a point p with norm = 2, so it is outside the unit Disk, can I find the reflection of this point inside the unit Disk?

Thanks

Comment: In the hyperboloid model $\{\vec p=(x,y,z)\mid\vec p\cdot\vec p= x^2+y^2-z^2=-1\}$, the upper sheet $z>0$ corresponds to the inside of the disk, and the lower sheet corresponds to the outside. The function $\vec p\mapsto-\vec p$ may be what you're looking for. (Another obvious candidate is $(x,y,z)\mapsto(x,y,-z)$, but this is not invariant under hyperbolic rotations.)

Comment: Thanks a lot   ; )